Are USB to PCIe bridges possible, such as the Broadcom USB 3380, and if so, how?
To my knowledge, it is not possible to connect a PCIe device over USB as PCIe to USB bridges do not exist. This is both due to USB lacking DMA, and USB having a latency of ~30 microseconds compared to PCIe's latency of ~2000 nanoseconds. It is possible to bridge USB to PCIe NVMe or SATA storage however, as there's a a microcontroller that appears as a host to the SSD, and as a USB storage device to the computer.
However, I have found the USB 3380 by Broadcom, that seems to do this. It's datasheet mentions that "The main applications for the USB 3380 as a PCI Express root complex include WLAN dongles, graphics/video dongles, and HDTV tuners/codec" which means that it isn't limited to NVMe storage devices. It also says that it has "Four Descriptor-based DMA channels for automatic data transfers" and its block diagram includes DMA.
This intrigues me, as I didn't think this was possible. It might implement DMA with special drivers, as the text mentions its drivers stack, which USB to NVMe bridges don't have as they just use standard USB BOT / UASP drivers, though I don't understand what they did about the latency problems. I know that PCIe can work with retimers and switches which can add latency, but I'm not sure if PCIe can work with this much latency. I was wondering if I misread the datasheet, and if not, I would be curious to understand how this device works. I have a very limited knowledge of computers, so if this question doesn't make sense, I'm open to improving it. Thank you for reading.
